How do I enumerate registry entries in powershell with wmi?
I'm trying to enumerate the registry valuenames in FirewallRules.
The code I have is not working, what is wrong with it?
$HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE =2147483650 
$Key = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\FirewallRules"
$names = $null
$valueTypes = $null
$namespace = "root\default"
$reg = Get-WmiObject -Namespace $namespace -Class StdRegProv    # Not Working, something is wrong.

$reg.EnumValues($HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, $Key, [ref]$names, [ref]$valueTypes)



Do not use wmi cmdlets use cim cmdlets(Get-CimInstance in this case); 2. what do you expect getting and what are you getting?


Get-NetFirewallRule ??

I need to check if an app makes holes in the firewall.
